# Optional Foreign Key in Access 2013 Table

Tags: ms-access, foreign-keys, ms-access-2013

It's been a very long time since I've used Access in earnest and I'm struggling with something! I'm much more comfortable with SQL these days!

I have two tables, let's say Customer and RelationshipStatus (I'm making these up for the purpose of illustration!). In my Customer table I have a `RelationshipStatusID` column (Type: Number) which is linked to the `ID` (Primary Key, Type: AutoNumber) column of the RelationshipStatus table. A standard one-to-many join.

I have also checked the `Enforce Referential Integrity` box for the join because I don't want people to be able to enter a value in the `RelationshipStatusID` column which is not a valid ID in the RelationshipStatus table, or to be able to delete a relationship status with related records in the Customer table.

Finally, in the Join Type I have specified "Include ALL records from 'Customer' and only those records from 'RelationshipStatus' where the joined fields are equal".

The problem is that this relationship is optional. I want to be able to create Customer records with no linked RelationshipStatus record. However, when I try to edit data in a subform of a new Customer record, I get the error "You cannot add or change a record because a related record is required in table 'RelationshipStatus'.

I have done some searching on this, and I think my problem may be that my Foreign Key column in Customer (`RelationshipStatusID`) has a default value of 0, which obviously isn't a valid ID in the RelationshipStatus table. However, I am unable to remove that default value in the Table definition, or to set it to NULL.

What am I doing wrong? Does enforcing referential integrity make a linked record mandatory? If not, how can I remove that default value for the Foreign Key column which is (I think) causing the error?

Comment: It should be no problems with deleting default value from `RelationshipStatusID`. At least I was able to do this and a lot of my databases have similar structure. Try to recreate  Customer table, delete default value before saving.

Comment: Sounds like you've found the issue - the default value. You should be able to remove it. It is a linked table. If so, you need to do it in the source file. What happens when you try to remove it?

Comment: Access doesn't have a concept of `NOT NULL`, it just has required and non-required fields. Make sure `Required` is set to `False` on the `RelationshipStatusID` column. That should allow you to leave it empty. If you're using a linked table, you need to make sure you're allowing `NULL` in the column

Comment: Why don't you add a record `0 - undefined` (or "unknown") to your `RelationshipStatus` table? Would be a cleaner solution imho.

Comment: `CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO RelationshipStatus (ID, RelStatusName) VALUES (0, 'unknown')"` works fine with ID being an Autonumber column and Primary Key. @ErikvonAsmuth

Comment: @Andre Sorry, you're right. Last time I tried I got a key violation, but I now remember that was on a linked table on another backend

Comment: "Required" *is* NOT NULL. The default for a nullable/non-required field is null. The "default" is for when a field is required. You need required=false.

Comment: @Andre  Why a "cleaner solution" to add a bogus value just to satisfy a mis-configured relationship?  That's a lazy and problematic solution imho.  That immediately removes the utility of many joins which depend on null matches and forevermore requires that an extra condition be put on many/all queries, always checking for and/or excluding the "0 - unknown" value.  It goes against good, normalized RDB design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the problem was indeed the default value of 0 for my Foreign Key columns in the table design, but for some reason I wasn't able to delete the default values at the time I wrote my question. After a reboot of the PC (and a weekend off, maybe that helped!) I was able to delete the default values in the Foreign Key columns and all was well.